# Reactjs & springboot: Sending request with jwt in authorization headers in reactjs not working. Anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors

Im trying to send a request in ReactJS to a Springboot backend. When I send a request without using headers, it works fine. But when I use headers, I get this error:

```
p://localhost:8080/test/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I send the request in postman, it works fine.
[postman request with headers result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zzbg.png)

But when I send it in react, It dosent work.

[getting token - works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsQx7.png)

[sending requests - the one WITHOUT headers works fine, the two WITH headers dosen't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HwqG.png)

[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQgrD.png)

[network tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGgYY.png)

This is my code for the controller, where the requests are handled:

The request to /all requiers no headers.

The requests to /user and /admin requiers headers

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestAccess {

    @GetMapping("/user") //requires headers
    public ResponseEntity<String> user() {
        System.out.println("user accessed");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User access");
    }


    @GetMapping("/admin") //requiers headers
    public ResponseEntity<String> admin() {
        System.out.println("admin accessed");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Admin access");
    }

    @GetMapping("/all") //dosent require headers
    public ResponseEntity<String> all() {
        System.out.println("accessed all");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("All access");
    }

}
```

This is my code for getting the token in reactjs (and it works).
Im using username and password to get a token, and then I save the token to local storage

```
    function authenticate() {
      axios.post(link, {
        username: "siggen123",
        password: "123123"
      })
      .then((response) => {
  
        console.log(response.data)
  
        if (response.data.token) {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
  
        return response.data;
      });
  
      
    }
```

This is my code for sending the requests
Im extracting the token from the local storage, and then I put it in the Authorization headers in the requests.

```
function Test() {
    let API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/test/"
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token;

    const getPublicContent = () => {
        axios.get(API_URL + "all").then((response) => console.log(response.data));
      };

    const getAdminContent = () => {
      return axios.get(API_URL + "admin", { headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (token) } }).then((response) => console.log(response.data));
    };

    const getUserContent = () => {
      return axios.get(API_URL + "user", { headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (token) } }).then((response) => console.log(response.data));
    };
    


  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={getPublicContent}>public</button>
        <button onClick={getUserContent}>user</button>
        <button onClick={getAdminContent}>admin</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've searched around some bit, but havent found anyting.
I found this piece of code, which someone was recommended to add to their springboot project. I added it to my own springboot project, but it dosen't solve the issue.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }


}
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?